# Partially processing a catalog with an extent in lidR

Tags: dem, buffer, lidar, extents, lidr

I am using `lidR` to create a DEM of a very large area (over 1 million hectares). I have already processed a portion of this area.

I would like to be able to read the entire `LAScatalog` so that the tiles I still need to process can access bordering tiles and use them as buffers, but don't know how to avoid processing the rest of the catalog.

I have been looking at the partial processing option as well as the `catalog_intersect()` function. I can make a raster of the area that I have already processed and get the extent and use `catalog_intersect()` to eliminate the tiles I have already processed, but that would also remove the tiles that would be needed as buffers.

Is there a way to use the `ctg$processed` option to select only the area not covered by a particular extent or spatial object for processing? Or is there a way to access the numbers assigned to each chunk of the catalog so that I can export the spatial object, intersect it with the processed area, and then use the `ctg$processed` option to select the unprocessed area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `catalog_select(..., method = "flag_unprocessed")` to interactively click on tiles you don't want to process (those that will be used as buffer only) or you can convert your `LAScatalog` into a pure `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to apply geometry operations. Below an example removing 10 km to the bounding box of the collection.

```r
library(lidR)
ctg <- readLAScatalog("folder/")

bbox <- extent(ctg) - 10000
bbox <- as(bbox, 'SpatialPolygons')  
spctg <- as.spatial(ctg)
ctg$processed <- rgeos::gIntersects(bbox, spctg, byid = TRUE)
plot(ctg)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This worked perfectly.